# Display all product tags in homepage

Tags: template, home, phtml, tags

I can't understand how can I display all tags in my homepage?

There's a workable solution to display a product's tags in a product page with this code:

```
<?php
// instantiate the tags class for products
$_tags = new Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List();
?>

<!-- ProductTags: -->
<ul class="product-tags">
<?php foreach($_tags->getTags() as $tag):?>
    <li><a href="<?=$tag->getTaggedProductsUrl()?>"><?=$tag->getName()?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work in home page.

I get error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `getItems()` on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php on line 45

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get programmatically popular tag use this code

```
    $tagmodel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $collection = $tagmodel->getResourceCollection()
                                ->addPopularity()

                                ->load();
foreach($collection as $tag)
                            {
                                //code here
                                }
```

Comment: hello! You write "to get popular tag", but I get all the tags with your code, not only popular. Anyway seems like this is what I need. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the Content section of your hopepage:

```
{{block type="tag/all" name="tags_all" template="tag/popular.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I need to get all tags, not only popular.

Comment: the block `tag/all` will give you all tags. The block uses the `popular` template but it should display all the tags.

Answer (score 0):

updated

```
$tag_model= Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
          $tag_collection= $tag_model->getResourceCollection()
                    ->addPopularity()
                    ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
                    ->addProductFilter($ProductId)
                    ->setFlag('relation', true)
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->setActiveFilter()
                    ->load();

    $mytags=$tag_collection->getItems();

       foreach ($mytags as $tag) {
               echo  $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();
               echo $tag->getName();

                      }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work. I get error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getResourceCollection() on a non-object in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 352

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this answer because the other answers are not working for me. I archived in the following way:

```
<?php $tagblockobj = Mage::getBlockSingleton('tag/all');?>
 <?php if( sizeof($tagblockobj ->getTags()) > 0 ): ?>
   <?php foreach($tagblockobj ->getTags() as $tag):?>
     <a href="<?php echo $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl()?>" class="tags-b"><?php echo $tag->getName()?></a>
   <?php endforeach;?>  
 <?php else: ?>
      <p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no tags available.') ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```